# Table Columns to Lists with Headers as List Names in Python

Tags: python, list, header, tabular

I have something like, in file example, file1.in

[image: example table]

I want lists `a = [1,4,...] b = [2,5,...]` you get the gist. I see various topics that get close to this but nothing explicit. So how can I convert this basic table format separated by white space into lists from the columns, using the column header as the list name? I'd prefer it be flexible by column number and length...

Comment: Its not clear what software or systems you are asking about. We need more details so the right experts can answer.

Comment: Sorry I should have said I'm using python.